# How to transform a Scala application into a single-instance persistant HTTP service?

Tags: java, web-services, scala

I've developed an application making intense use of runtime memoization.

I'd like to convert it into a web service. The service main class should exist in one instance to process all the requests and not shut down but wait (keeping all the values) for further requests when all requests are processed.

There are meant to be only a couple of clients (all of them 100% trusted) and pretty rare requests (so I don't need a too serious application server and can even survive without requests processing parallelization), but heavy data-crunching-intense tasks to be made on requests (unless all needed data is already memoized).

I have no skill of web/EE Java and servlets yet.

Comment: Does it must be web? Have you considered other protocols (RMI, JMS, for dealing with very few requests even raw Sockets is a option).

Comment: @pedrofurla, IMHO web service interface looks more 'civilized', compatible, extensible and easy to fit in mind. IMHO web services should be favoured to raw sockets and any other special protocols unless there are very large amounts of data to be transmitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest would be to [embed Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).

Comment: Yeah, Jetty would be the easiest solution.

Comment: +1: I do this with a regular Java app and the Simple HTTP server: http://simpleweb.sourceforge.net/